# Putting data from SQL query into grid view asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a grid box in which I want to fill data from a database where the username is one and their location was added in the last 24 hours.

I have tested the SQL query and it is working fine, however when trying to put the data in a grid box nothing happens.

Here is the code I have used in the aspx.cs file:

```
    public partial class last24hours : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = sql2008.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk; Initial Catalog = rde_514872; Integrated Security = True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location FROM StaffLocation WHERE [Date and Time]>= getdate()-1 AND [Username] = '1'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gridView1 is an empty grid view I have made with no sql source.

This is how the gridview is initialised in the aspx file:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Run the program with the debugger attached, set a breakpoint, and inspect `dt` when you bind it to the GridView? Does it have data? What does the declaration for `GridView` look like?

Comment: I tested your code and it works just fine. Either the connection is incorrect or the query does not return any data. I suspect `getdate()-1`, it's a weird construction. Better use sql `DATEADD`.

Comment: The dt is showing the correct table, I will also put up my aspx code for the grid view in case there is an error there

Comment: If you have `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and you aren't specifying the columns in your markup, how is the GridView going to show anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have AutoGenerateColumns set to false. And since you haven't defined any columns manually, *of course* nothing is going to show up. There's two fixes:

Set auto generate columns to true.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

Or manually define your columns

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! You're a life saver